# How to trigger a sysdiagnose on iOS 14.4+ device

Tags: ios, bug-reporting, sysdiagnose

I have an iPhone 8, and I'm trying to trigger a sysdiagnose with iOS 14.4 and up. You'd think that this is well-documented, and it is, but I still can't get it to work.

Here's what I've tried:

If you go to the Profiles and logs page here and filter by iOS: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?platform=ios

There is documentation labelled "Sysdiagnose" which takes you here: https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/iOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf

The instructions are pretty straightforward.

Hold the two volume buttons and the side button for 1-1.5 seconds.

**Expected results**

It says a screenshot will be taken and a sysdiagnose will be triggered.

**Actual results**

The Emergency-SOS/Power-Off screen shows, and the SOS swipe gradually counts down and starts making loud-AF emergency beeps while it counts down, sort of like when you get an Amber Alert. This is sort of terrifying.

There is no screenshot taken, and if I wait, it does not yield anything resembling a sysdiagnose in the Settings.app > Privacy > Analytics > Analytics Data

**Other things I've tried**

- Searched Apple's forums, tried all options recommended here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/80811
- Tried using the home button instead of the side button... same results as above.

Thanks for any help or clarification!

Do I really have to risk accidentally calling the Police (or whatever SOS does) to trigger a sysdiagnose?

Are there some steps I'm missing? Like my device should be plugged into my mac and debugging on XCode? Or showing in the Organizer?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to release all of the buttons pretty quick, within the 1-1.5 second timeframe. If you hold the buttons longer it won't work.

If you're waiting for the phone to confirm that a sysdiagnose is triggered before releasing the buttons, then you're doing it wrong. Release them within 1-1.5 seconds.

Second,

If you're waiting for a screenshot to be taken as the documentation says it will, it won't happen... at least the way you're used to where the screen obviously shrinks and shows your screenshot in the bottom left for a few seconds. This WILL NOT HAPPEN, so don't expect this as any sort of indication your sysdiagnose was successfully triggered.

Third,

When you're looking for the sysdiagnose file, you really have to scroll ALL THE WAY DOWN the list of logs and such until you literally see something called sysdiagnose.

Make sure you wait a bit before looking.

Settings.app > Privacy > Analytics > Analytics Data

Fourth,

If you feel a slight vibration and nothing else happens, you probably did it right.

I tried clearing this list out so it was clearer where my sysdiagnose was, and syncing your device or resetting the Location and Privacy settings won't do it as suggested here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250201909

Hope this helps someone that is as dense as me.

Answer (score 0):

I find it much easier to run sysdiagnose using Assistive Touch.

Settings > Accessibility > Touch > AssitiveTouch > on
Settings > Accessibility > Touch > AssitiveTouch > Customize Top Level Menu
... and add new icon for "Analytics"

Now you can run sysdiagnose just by tapping a button on the screen.

For a detailed tutorial see the following instructions provided by Apple: [Using Sysdiagnose to Troubleshoot iOS or iPadOS](https://it-training.apple.com/tutorials/support/sup075).